# Continue with polymer 1.x or wait for polymer 2.x to be available?

Tags: user-interface, polymer

I'm currently planning to refresh one of our dashboard wish is currently build on polymer 1.x line.

However, as I saw that Polymer 2.x series is on its way and that (as usual with google) a lot of things will be broken and need a migration, I'm wondering if it is better to wait the polymer 2.x release to be out or to start building our new dashboard relying on our already created Polymer 1.x components?

I'm not in a hurry and can wait for a couple or more month.
I really want to stay with polymer and don't want to switch to angular or react as those library/framework/whatever are really not adapted for this projects (Too complex and server side generated).

Currently this dashboard is an all client side dynamic page and call APIs which them are NodeJS apps underneath.

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.7 of polymer you can start leveraging features from the 2.x branch that has been made available to prepare for the upgrade.

> Polymer 1.7.0 provides forward compatibility features that let you build elements that run under both 1.0 and 2.0.
>
> While you can use these features now, the team intends to release a tool to help automate these changes. If you have a large project, you might want to wait for the migration tool to be available.
>
> The new syntax is not required for current Polymer 1.x elements, but using the new syntax will make it easier to port elements to 2.0, which requires it.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-10-03-1.7-release

Comment: Oh, that is interesting ! Is polymer 2.x line currently stabilized or will the syntax and building block still subjects to major evolve/shifts ?